# how to repeat in Fiji

Tags: repeat, imagej, imagej-macro

I was wondering if it is possible to write in into macro to repeat just a part of the macro in imageJ.

I have a code

```
selectWindow("Red");
run("Duplicate...", " ");
rename("Red-Dup");
run("8-bit");
run("Subtract...", "value=25");
run("Duplicate...", " ");
imageCalculator("Add create", "Red-Dup","Red-Dup-1");
run("Subtract...", "value=25");
close("Red-Dup");
close("Red-Dup-1");
```

and instead of copying and pasting it 20 times, I would like to find a function to run it let's say x20.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You only need a for loop:

```
num_of_repeat = 20
for (i = 0; i < num_of_repeat; i++){

   selectWindow("Red");
   run("Duplicate...", " ");
   rename("Red-Dup");
   run("8-bit");
   run("Subtract...", "value=25");
   run("Duplicate...", " ");
   imageCalculator("Add create", "Red-Dup","Red-Dup-1");
   run("Subtract...", "value=25");
   close("Red-Dup");
   close("Red-Dup-1");

}
```

And you can change the `num_of_repeat`, if you want to change the number of repetition.